# Work on samples instead of the entire data base

Tags: sql, database

I'd like to know if it's common pratice to create a CUSTOMER_RANDOM_VALUE (between 0 and 100) in order to work on random sample instead of the entire data base.

Let's take an example : you manage the CDW of a webstore and you use an incremental CustomerID.

If you want to know the numbers of users who visit the page of a specific product a you need to do that :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID)
FROM WEBSITE_TRAFFIC
WHERE PRODUCT_KEY= 134
```

The problem is this table is so huge that it could take 1h to know that and you have to answer lots of questions of this type all day long.

Why don't create a random_value for each customer :

```
Customer_Id | Random Value
 1               13
 2               41
 3               8
 4               87
```

and work on a sample of 1% like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID)
FROM WEBSITE_TRAFFIC
WHERE PRODUCT_KEY= 134
AND CUSTOMER_RANDOM_VALUE<1
```

**Question** : Is it a common pratice when the amount of data are huge,to use sampling with a CUSTOMER_RANDOM_VALUE.

Comment: A good practice would be to have an empty database. And then, have scripts that can issue series of inserts to load sample data. Then, any developer can have his own sample database to work his code against.

Comment: I would never do what you are contemplating.  I would add an index to the field I use in the where clause.  Also, for your specific example, I would add a date range to the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is too use the right tool. Most relational databases are very good at doing online transaction processing (OLTP) as they evolved primarily to solve that niche in the '80s and '90s. Queries like the one you propose are of a different kind, they are **analytical** queries (OLAP). To run analytic workloads there are better tools.

[**Columnstores**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS) are a primary example of a tool better suited for analytic processing and almost all platforms have a columnstore engine today.

**In memory** engines like [SQL Server Analysis Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Analysis_Services) are another approach.

Or ditch the database altogether and just process the web logs in Hadoop for analytics.

The problem is that having an OLTP system for your 'Products' *and* another OLAP system for your analytical insight is problematic. Sure, you can set up an ETL process to keep the OLAP system up-to-date, but is not easy.

The gist of it is that you have two contradicting forces tearing system apart: your OLTP requirements for serving the pages vs. the OLAP requirements for your analytics. You will not find a 'one-size-fits-all' answer, any single system trying to address both will be  a compromise, there are fundamentals at play here.

So, short time, you *may* get some mileage out of an appropriate index on `WEBSITE_TRAFFIC`. You may do some pre-aggregation and staging, with batched updates and some delay. But there is no silver bullet, easy answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.
I'm not technical at all and I don't decide which tool I use.

I just use database for uploading the data and do my statistical analysis.
Sometimes they asked me which proportion of our customers did that, and sampling seems a good way to speedup the query but nobody seems to do that so it looks like a wrong practice to me.